# Android SOAP problem

Tags: android

**I m making an application using SOAP in android. Actually i want to do login functionality by calling web service on click of login button.** In this i want the user to log in into application by checking that the user is registered or not(Webservice is sending successfull or failed respose). can anybody tell me the procedure or any nice tutorial or some sample code. it will b very helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the kSoap2 lib for Android. I found this video tutorial especially useful: http://www.vimeo.com/9633556 .

Apart from that, using SOAP in Android apps is discouraged, and not supported by the SDK. Consider using REST, if that's possible, it's more lightweight.